# SSJS Email.Retrieve function not getting emails

Tags: marketing-cloud, ssjs

I am using [this](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/ssjs_emailRetrieve.htm) function to check in SSJS if my email exists using the customer key.

Code:

```
  <script runat="server">
    Platform.Load("Core", "1.1.1");

    try {

      var emailKey = 'df_test_email';
      var results = Email.Retrieve({Property:"CustomerKey",SimpleOperator:"equals",Value:emailKey});
      if (results.length < 1) {
          Write("###Email Does Not Exist<br>");
      }
```

Problem is the results always return zero, even though I know there is an email with the customer key set to `df_test_email`.

[image]

Comment: I need to test, but this may not work for Content Builder emails. I'll test shortly and let you know

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you use the REST API for this?

```
<script runat = "server" >
Platform.Load("Core", "1");
var url = 'https://auth.exacttargetapis.com/v1/requestToken';
var contentType = 'application/json';
var request = {
  "clientId": "YOUR CLIENT ID",
  "clientSecret": "YOUR SECRET"
};
var payload = Platform.Function.Stringify(request);
var result = HTTP.Post(url, contentType, payload);
var aRes = Platform.Function.ParseJSON(result.Response.toString());
var auth = aRes.accessToken;
var url = 'https://www.exacttargetapis.com/asset/v1/content/assets/query';
var contentType = 'application/json';

var request = {
  "query": {
    "leftOperand": {
      "property": "assetType.id",
      "simpleOperator": "equals",
      "valueType": "int",
      "value": 208 //HTMLEmail type
    },
    "logicalOperator": "AND",
    "rightOperand": {
      "property": "name",
      "simpleOperator": "equals",
      "value": "df_test_email"
    }
  }
};
var payload = Platform.Function.Stringify(request);
var headerNames = ["Authorization"];
var headerValues = ["Bearer " + auth];
var result = HTTP.Post(url, contentType, payload, headerNames, headerValues);
var res = result.Response.toString();
</script>
```

Comment: I am building this piece of code in SSJS, if there is already a built in SSJS function I'd prefer to use this than resort to using the API within SSJS. Trying to figure out if theres something wrong with the syntax or I'm not doing something quite right.

Comment: To my knowledge there is not a built in function like that which will retrieve a content builder asset. You have to use the REST API. Updated my answer to include the full snippet.

Comment: Just realised I've been trying to recreate the wheel when you've already provided the answer to getting the ID via API here. The same issue still occurs here "System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.String,System.Object]".

Comment: FYI there is a much smaller resource you can use if you append the ID after `/assets/` instead of `query`. 132KB vs 4.4MB

Comment: Despite using a filter condition it looks like its just returning all the assets, hence the large payload. (4.3MB)

Comment: That's a good point, will run some tests on that on my end as well. Usually if I'm just running a GET request to retrieve data on a single ID I'll just use Postman rather than using the query method above since it's faster, so that may be why I've never noticed the performance issue.

Comment: I've been testing in Postman and it works correct, but using `HTTP.Get` I can't parse the response even though the result is also JSON. Can I not use the same `result.Response.toString()`?

Comment: Yeah you definitely can, but I find I always get an error (unable to retrieve security descriptor for this frame) for all my GET requests on a cloudpage. Works great outside the system or in script activities, but it's annoyed me enough that I never make GET requests on cloudpages anymore.

Comment: So, even though you could parse the response with that same code (because it's literally the same format), you never can get the JSON response returned; just an error.

Comment: Thanks, I've reverted back to your version but changed the filter criteria to get smaller responses.

Answer (score 1):

This may be that you want:

```
function getemailname(pEID)
       {
          var myEmail = Email.Init("myEmail");
          myEmail =  Email.Retrieve({Property:"ID",SimpleOperator:"equals",Value:pEID});

          for (var i = 0; i < myEmail.length; i++)
          {
              return (myEmail[i].Name);
          }

     }
```

The reference is from https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/ssjs_retrieveExternalKey.htm?search_text=Email.Retrieve

Comment: This does not retrieve content builder assets.